# What happened to my cat, who suddenly died?

Tags: cats, death

Wondering if anyone would be able to tell me what happened to my cat, Twitch. On December 5th my guy passed away. It was extremely extremely sudden. The night before he was fine and happy. But I woke up on Friday morning and he was laying weird. So I went over to him and noticed he couldn’t hold himself up or move his legs at all. So I made him as comfortable as I could. I was going to bring him to the vet, but I sadly did not have the money at the time. So about an hour later I tried to see if I could get him to drink some water. And he gagged the second the water touched his tongue. Then a few hours after that he started having small seizures. And that was on and off for a couple hours. Then he passed away in the morning on Saturday :(

Comment: i am sorry for your loss and i know how hard it is to loose a pet.i do not think it is possible to find the cause for your cat passing away with the details in your question but it sounds like your cat might have had a stroke or some sort of heart failiure.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your cat caught a disease and it happened or maybe some internal issue was caused in the stomach or in the appendix. It may be that your cat licked salt that people put on the snow since it is winter. Next time you own a cat and it snows, make sure that you wipe off your cat before they come in or not let them outside. Salt is a big issue for cats so in general, don’t let cats eat salt from the snow.